# $.post not working in ie. Alternative way help please?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I used $.post to send and receive response in my web page. But it is not working in Internet Explorer. I used other way of Ajax. I have to create xmlhttprequest object.

My code is

```
     var xmlhttp;
     if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
       {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
       xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
       }
     else
       {// code for IE6, IE5
         xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }
          xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
         {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
       {
       document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
     xmlhttp.open("POST","demo_post2.asp",true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      xmlhttp.send("fname=Henry&lname=Ford");
```

This works fine with all browser except ie-10. I write code like below to support ie-10.

```
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0");
      }
```

It is not working with mozila, safari but working with ie-10. I have not checked with ie-7. It is a conflict. Please provide me any help please...........

Comment: Showing code that "`$.post`  is not working in Internet Explorer" may be better approach...

Comment: What's wrong with jQuery.post or jQuery.ajax?

Answer (score 0):

try going with the first approach and encapsule your send function as shownn below

```
setTimeout(function () {
xmlhttp.send();
}, 0);
```